# How do I make my list extension return more than one result?

Tags: visualforce, apex

Currently, I'm only able to return one result because I have specified exactly what campaign I want returned this this line:

```
SELECT Id from campaign WHERE Id = '701i0000000JXz5'
```

I want my page to list all campaigns that have a specific field set to a specific status. When I change the line given above to something like:

```
SELECT Id from campaign WHERE Type = 'Direct Mail'
```

I get the following error:

`System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject`

Something I've done is limiting my list to one item, but I'm not sure what it is.

Here is the visual force page:

```
<apex:page standardController="campaign" recordSetVar="dmcampaigns" extensions="DirectMailfilter">  <apex:form >
     <apex:pageBlock title="Direct Mail">
             <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!dmcampaigns}" var="s">
                  <apex:column value="{!s.StartDate}"/>
                  <apex:column value="{!s.Type}"/>  
                  <apex:column value="{!s.status}"/>     
                  <apex:column value="{!s.Name}"/>
             </apex:pageBlockTable> 
     </apex:pageBlock> </apex:form> </apex:page>
```

**with this extension:**

```
public class DirectMailfilter {

public id camRecId;

public DirectMailfilter(ApexPages.StandardsetController controller) {

camRecId = [SELECT Id from campaign WHERE Id = '701i0000000JXz5'].id;

}

List<campaign> dmcampaigns;

public List<campaign> getdmcampaigns() {
    if(camRecId != null) {
    dmcampaigns= [SELECT StartDate, Type, Status, Name 
                    FROM Campaign 
                    WHERE campaign.id=:camRecId];
    }
return dmcampaigns;
}  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error I think you've been applying the new filter to the 1st query (`camRecId`). But your "list of campaigns" is queried for below!

You don't really need that query, it can be simplified to something like this:

```
public class DirectMailfilter {
    public List<campaign> dmcampaigns {get;private set;}

    public DirectMailfilter(ApexPages.StandardsetController controller) {
        dmcampaigns = [SELECT StartDate, Type, Status, Name 
                    FROM Campaign 
                    WHERE Type = 'Direct Mail'];
    }
}
```

The query will be run only once (when the constructor runs on first page load) whereas in your old code you would send a query every time getter is called (for example every time you hit some form submission buttons).

You can read more about the getters/setters [here](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2008/06/property-access.html)